# Is this final gravity too high?

Tags: fermentation, original-gravity, stout, final-gravity, lactose

I brewed a Chocolate Oatmeal Milk Stout with an OG of 1.062. After 2.5 weeks of what seemed like active fermentation, it's only at 1.030. It's been at that for a week. It tastes like a it will be a good stout, but the FG seems high. There is 1 lbs. of lactose in there, which might be the reason the gravities are higher.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Must see a recipe to really dig into the issue.  % lactose and % specialty malts especially.

Answer (score 3):

Really can't say how the lactos is effecting the gravity with out the whole recipe.

It's very likely it can finish out the remaining points with some time and warmth. Bring it up to 70°F and give it a swirl to stir up the yeast.

1.030 is only a few points off from the high end of a sweet stout's FG of 1.024.